# CSV input redirection through CLI

Tags: rust, rust-polars

I'm trying to import input CSV through CLI into Polars (Rust) DataFrame, however, cannot appear to do so.

Currently this is the process, which fails:

```rust
use std::io::{Stdin, stdin};
use polars::prelude::*;
fn load_file(file: Stdin) -> LazyFrame {
    let lazy_df = CsvReader::from(file);

    match lazy_df {
        Ok(good_df) => good_df,
        Err(error) => panic!("{}", error),
    }
}

fn main() {
    let reader = io::stdin();
    let mut buffer = String::new();
    reader
        .lock()
        .read_to_string(&mut buffer)
        .expect("Failed in reading the file");

    let df = load_file(reader);
}
```

exec:
`cargo run < data/play_data.csv`

Comment: looked at Polars docs, there is a sample to load CSV from file. Do you persist on converting `Stdin` into a `CsvReader`? Read from file sample: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/examples/read_csv/src/main.rs

Comment: @Raeisi it throws an error: the trait `MmapBytesReader` is not implemented for `Stdin`

Comment: as you can see the `Stdin` isn't part of the acceptable traits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a work around using `Cursor`. Polars has [implementation](https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/main/crates/polars-io/src/mmap.rs) for `impl<T> MmapBytesReader for Cursor<T>`.

First read the entire `Stdin` into a vector, then transform it into a cursor. At the end convert the cursor into a Polars expected type.

```rust
use std::io::{Read, Stdin};
use polars::io::mmap::MmapBytesReader;
use polars::prelude::*;

fn load_file(reader: &Stdin) -> () {
    let mut v = Vec::<u8>::new();
    reader
        .lock()
        .read_to_end(&mut v)
        .expect("cannot read from stdin")
    ;

    let cursor = std::io::Cursor::new(v);
    let file = Box::new(cursor) as Box<dyn MmapBytesReader>;

    let df = CsvReader::new(file)
        .with_delimiter(b',')
        .has_header(true)
        .finish()
        ;

    let df = match df {
        Ok(x) => x,
        Err(e) => {
            panic!("cannot load data frame: {}", e);
        }
    };

    let mask = df.column("Id").unwrap().i64().unwrap().gt_eq(100);
    let filter = df.filter(&mask).unwrap().mean();

    println!("filter: {filter}");
}

fn main() {
    let reader = std::io::stdin();
    load_file(&reader);
}
```

Comment: Was looking for something like, wanted to actually split using CSV crates, however, you have a better solution. You should really make this into PR for Polars lib.